# Unity WWW webrequest not executing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

I have a unity program that changes it content based on the data requested from a webserver. I wrote the following code to do the web-request.

```
public static string[] GetDBValues(int type, string[] data){
    string base_url = "http://localhost/artez/onderzoeks_opdracht/interface_test/get_elements.php";
    string typePrefix = "?type=";
    string dataPrefix = "data[]=";
    string uriString = base_url + typePrefix + type;
    foreach (string dataElement in data){
        uriString += "&" + dataPrefix + dataElement;
    }
    Debug.Log("executing url request");
    UrlData(uriString);
    return new string[] {"a"};
}

public static IEnumerator UrlData(string url){
    Debug.Log("searching the web");
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url)){
        Debug.Log(www.text);
        yield return www.text;
    }
}
```

this code compiles and executes but i never see the following `Debug.Log("searching the web")` being logged. So i believe my code never executes the last part why is this happening?
I am a complete newb to c#.

If something is unclear let me know so i can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues in your code:

**1**.The `UrlData` function is a coroutine function. You have to use `StartCoroutine` to call it instead of calling it irectly like a normal function.  So, `UrlData(uriString);` should be `StartCoroutine(UrlData(uriString));`

**2**.You have to yield or wait for the `WWW` request to finish before accessing the `WWW.text` property. That should be `yield return www` not `yield return www.text`.

```
public static IEnumerator UrlData(string url)
{
    Debug.Log("searching the web");
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
    }
}
```

**3**.It looks like you want `GetDBValues` to return the result from the `UrlData` function. If this is true then just add `Action` as argument to the `UrlData` function so that you can use that to return the result.

Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerator UrlData(string url, Action<string> result)
{
    Debug.Log("searching the web");
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        if (result != null)
            result(www.text);
    }
}
```

then start it like below. The result is in the `result` variable:

```
StartCoroutine(UrlData("url", (result) =>
{
    Debug.Log(result);
}));
```

Comment: I added your suggestion but now i get the following compile errors: `An object reference is required for the non static field, method, or property 'MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)'` and the next error is `the type or namespace 'Action<>' could not be found`

Comment: `Action` requires `using System;`. What ever script you are calling `StartCoroutine` function from must inherit from Monobehavior and you need to make sure you are **not** calling it from `static` function. If you are calling  `StartCoroutine`  from `GetDBValues ` then remove the `static` keyword in the `GetDBValues`  function.